# Can I use a Tokenizer from a Hugginface model via HF inference API?

Tags: nlp, huggingface

I know I can use the Huggingface inference API to access a model. Following that logic I could replace my expensive `AutoModel.from_pretrained(...)` and shift the heavy-lifting in the huggingface inference API.

Can I use the same API to "lift" `AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(...)`?

What about (eg) `AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(...)`?